# Send value of input text box from jQuery slider through Submit Button Using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

The value of the sliders are displayed in an input textbox. When i move the slider, the value in the textboxes changes accordingly. I echoed the values from the textboxes in another php page and they are 0. And when i click the submit button it still echoes the number 0. For example, i moved the slider to 720 but when i click the submit button it still displays 0. Please help me with this. Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance. Here is the code for the form, **index.php**:

```
    <form method="POST" action="index.php">

<p class="submitSlider">
    <input type="SUBMIT" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="showAvailable()">
</p>

<div id="slider1Containter">
    <p>
        Time Range: <span class="slider-time">10:00 AM</span>
    </p>
    <input type="number" id="startShift" name="startShiftSlider">
    <div id="slider"></div>
</div>

<div id="slider2Containter">
    <p>
        Time Range: <span class="slider-time2">10:00 AM</span>
    </p>
    <input type="number" id="endShift" name="endShiftSlider">
    <div id="slider2"></div>
</div>

</form>
```

And here is the entire code of the **seatmap.php**:

```
<?php  
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
session_start();

$startShift = $_POST['startShiftSlider'];
$endShift = $_POST['endShiftSlider'];

$_SESSION['startShiftValue'] = $startShift;
$_SESSION['endShiftValue'] = $endShift;

$finalStartShiftValue = $_SESSION['startShiftValue'];
$finalEndShiftValue = $_SESSION['endShiftValue'];

echo $finalStartShiftValue;
echo $finalEndShiftValue;
}
?>
```

And for the javascript/ajax function in the **functions.js**:

```
function showAvailable(){
  var xmlhttp;

  var getStartShift;
  var getEndShift;

  if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else{
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
      if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
        getStartShift = document.getElementById("startShift").value;
        getEndShift = document.getElementById("endShift").value;

        xmlhttp.open("GET","seatmap.php?sendStartShift="+getStartShift+"&sendEndShift="+getEndShift,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
      }
  }  
}
```

This might be a duplicate from another SO forum as i've just followed the codes from that forum.

Oh, and here is the **CSS**:

```
body{
font-family: tahoma;
margin: 50px;
font-size: 15px;
}

#slider{
width: 400px;
}  

#slider2{
width: 400px;
}

#slider1Containter{
display: inline-block;
}

#slider2Containter{
display: inline-block;
}

.submitSlider input{
border-radius: 0;
border: 0px none;
background-color: #00A0D1;
padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
color: white;
}

.submitSlider input:hover{
color: black;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: be sure to remove the extra semicolons in your `seatmap.php` script at `$finalEndShift = intval($_REQUEST['sendEndShift']);;` and the previous line

Comment: Already did, thanks for noting that and thank you for your time..

Comment: you know that the `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` function is not going to execute before `xmlhttp.open(...)` right? and that in that line the variables `getStartShift` and `getEndShift` are not declared, because you made it local to the `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` function

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't know that. I'm just a beginner. Thank you though for that. So how should i put it? Any ideas?

Comment: whaaat? do this `alert("seatmap.php?sendStartShift="+getStartShift+"&sendEndShift="+getEndShift);` before `xmlhttp.open()` and share what it shows

Comment: The slider vanishes whenever i add this code...

Comment: okay, but what does the alert show?

Comment: The slider vanishes, and then i manually input a value in the slider and click the submit button. But then nothing happens, no alerts show up..

Comment: okay, please add your css to the question for the slider please

Comment: it could also be that the problem is happening somewhere else in your seatmap.php, but we can't help you with it, because you only shared 4lines with us

Comment: @pythonian29033 I've already inlcuded **all** the codes in all php and js pages. Sorry to include all codes. I don't know what to do anymore..

Comment: okay, first of all; delete `session_start();` from seatmap.php, you already have it at the top of index.php

Comment: I'm gonna have to set this up on my side so I can find if and where the problem is now, I'm only going on lunch in two hours, you'll have to wait a while man, I'm at work quickly

Comment: Ok man, no problem, take your time. Just keep working on it. I will come back tomorrow. It's 5:20 now in our country. I'll come back 9:30 am the next day..

Comment: @pythonian29033 Hello? You still there? My friend got it work but I have one minor problem though. Why is the page reloading when i click the submit button and what is the AJAX function there for if it is reloading. I feel like the AJAX function isn't being used because as you can see in the **seatmap.php** (I put the edited codes by the way and put the new codes from my friend) the value was fetched from the form. Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

the `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` function is not going to execute before `xmlhttp.open(...)` this function will only get executed when the readystate of the webpage has changed, and the browser calls that function. 
In the line;

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","seatmap.php?sendStartShift="+getStartShift+"&sendEndShift="+getEndShift,true);
```

your get request will equate to;

```
seatmap.php?sendStartShift=null&sendEndShift=null
```

since the variables `getStartShift` and `getEndShift` are not declared, because you made it local to the `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` function

try changing this;

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
   if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
   {
      var getStartShift = document.getElementById("startShift").value;
      var getEndShift = document.getElementById("endShift").value;
   }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","seatmap.php?sendStartShift="+getStartShift+"&sendEndShift="+getEndShift,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

to this;

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
   if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
   {
      var getStartShift = document.getElementById("startShift").value;
      var getEndShift = document.getElementById("endShift").value;

      xmlhttp.open("GET","seatmap.php?sendStartShift="+getStartShift+"&sendEndShift="+getEndShift,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
   }
}
```

alternatively, you could set the variables as global and use it this way;

```
   var getEndShift, getEndShift;
   function showAvailable(){
      var xmlhttp;

      getStartShift = document.getElementById("startShift").value;
      getEndShift = document.getElementById("endShift").value;

      if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }else{
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
          if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
          {
             getStartShift = document.getElementById("startShift").value;
             getEndShift = document.getElementById("endShift").value;
          }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","seatmap.php?sendStartShift="+getStartShift+"&sendEndShift="+getEndShift,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
   }
```

**Note that `var getEndShift, getEndShift;` happens OUTSIDE the function `showAvailable()` to make the variables global**

Comment: I tried it. Still didn't work though. Appreciate your help though.. Thanks.

Comment: I've tried that one too. Still didn't work. Should I post all the codes?